# Console prints the char's ASCII Value, not the sign itself

Tags: java

I have variable:

```java
char characterA = '#';
int arr = new arr[5][5];

arr[3][1] = characterA;
```

When I print the array it gives me its value, not the char itself. How can I show the char?

Comment: The code you've posted wouldn't compile, given that you're trying to assign an `int[][]` value to an `int` - but basically, if you want *character* values you should use `char` instead of `int`.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of a method from the Character class ?

Comment: If you use a method that allows you to define a format, use `%c` to print the value as a char. If not, you can cast it to char: `(char)arr[3][1]`.
Anyway,  I recommend you to use a `char[][]`.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a char[][] array instead of an int[][] array.
Since you are using an int array. java converts the character into it's ascii value and stores that

Comment: Java does not convert the character into "it's ascii value" (if anything it would be the Unicode codepoint value), but `char` in Java is already an integer type (which just happens to be "displayed"/handled as a character in most contexts).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store your char as an int (e.g if the array is created elsewere), you still can print it as char using the `printf` family of methods (`String.format`, `PrintStream.printf` etc) and modifier `%c`.

For example:

```java
char c = 'A';
int n = c; 
System.err.printf("%c", n); // prints 'A'
```

The full documentation on formatting syntax is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)